# Variadic template class expansion

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class where I want to cycle through the template types and do something for each type. This is a simplified example.

```
template<class... T>
class Handler
{
private:
    template<class A>
    void Do1_(int a, int b)
    { 
       A obj{};
       obj.Process(a, b);
    }

    template<class A, class... B>
    void Do_(int a, int b)
    {
        Do1_<A>(a, b);
        Do_<B...>(a, b);
    }
public:
     void Do(int a, int b)
    {
       Do_<T...>(a, b);
    }
};

struct Foo1 {
   void Process(int a, int b) {}
};
struct Foo2 {
   void Process(int a, int b) {}
};    
class Bar : public Handler<Foo1, Foo2> {};
```

But the expansion for `Do_<B...>` gives me trouble, I get compilation error about "could not deduce template argument for 'A'", when compiling `Do_<B...>`. What should be the correct expansion be here in order to make it compile, if possible.

Comment: For starters, using the proper ellipsis with three dots might be a good idea. As would telling us *what* troubles you have. If you have build errors, copy-paste (as text) them in full and complete and paste into the question. Something you really should know as such an old member with a few questions asked. If not then re-read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and re-learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have made some edits to make it a compelte example. Where am I using the wrong ellipsis?

Comment: What is the actual *problem* ? This code is so far removed from something sensible its borderline hurtful. Was there some specific reason you chose to reuse `b` as an id in `Do1_` ??

Comment: @WhozCraig, it is a very simplified example, my problem is that the compiler complains about wrong expansion

Comment: `Do_<T..>(a, b)`. Perhaps this is the problem you have? Without knowing the errors you have (always include them!) it's not possible for us to help you really.

Comment: What does `B obj{};` mean, considering that `B` is not a single type but a parameter pack representing multiple types?

Comment: Sorry, the example was erronous, low bloodsugar. The example should be more correct now.

Comment: You need a specialization of `Do_` for zero template arguments - something to terminate the recursion. But really, you don't need a recursion at all: `template<class... A> void Do_(int a, int b) { int dummy[] = {(Do1_<A>(a, b), 0) ...}; }` In fact, you can just put that in `Do` - you don't need those helpers.

Comment: All your classes are missing semicolons at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating matters. This should do (no pun intended):

```
template<class... T>
class Handler
{
public:
    void Do(int a, int b) {
       int dummy[] = {(T{}.Process(a, b), 0)...};
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UEJ58879)

Comment: Thank you. But if I would like to do in along the lines I did, how would it be done, if possible? With this solution I would have to suppress warning about unused variable, can this be avoided? And what would you call the type of construct you have used, I have not seen it before.

Comment: It's just an array with initializer. Similar to `int dummy[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` It's just that the individual elements of the initializer happen to have side effects.